# ICustomTypeDescriptor with display

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi guys I am implementing the interface ICustomTypeDescriptor and binding to a WPF grid. I am having issues with result, was expecting just the single column "Random" but getting something totally different. Any help would be much appreciated. Andy

[image]

```
/// <summary>
/// Property Descriptor for Test Result Row Wrapper
/// </summary>
public class TestResultPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    //- PROPERTIES --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Component Type
    /// </summary>
    public override Type ComponentType
    {
        get { return typeof(Dictionary<string, TestResultValue>); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets whether its read only
    /// </summary>
    public override bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Property Type
    /// </summary>
    public override Type PropertyType
    {
        get { return typeof(string); }
    }

    #endregion Properties

    //- CONSTRUCTOR -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public TestResultPropertyDescriptor(string key)
        : base(key, null)
    {

    }

    #endregion Constructor

    //- METHODS -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Can Reset Value
    /// </summary>
    public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
    {
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Value
    /// </summary>
    public override object GetValue(object component)
    {
        return ((Dictionary<string, TestResultValue>)component)[base.Name].Value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Resets the Value
    /// </summary>
    public override void ResetValue(object component)
    {
        ((Dictionary<string, TestResultValue>)component)[base.Name].Value = string.Empty;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the value
    /// </summary>
    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
        ((Dictionary<string, TestResultValue>)component)[base.Name].Value = value.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets whether the value should be serialized
    /// </summary>
    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
    {
        return false;
    }

    #endregion Methods

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
/// <summary>
/// Class to manage test result row data functions
/// </summary>
public class TestResultRowWrapper : Dictionary<string, TestResultValue>, ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    //- METHODS -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Attributes for the object
    /// </summary>
    AttributeCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetAttributes()
    {
        return new AttributeCollection(null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Class name
    /// </summary>
    string ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetClassName()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the component Name
    /// </summary>
    string ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetComponentName()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Type Converter
    /// </summary>
    TypeConverter ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetConverter()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Default Event
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    EventDescriptor ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Default Property
    /// </summary>
    PropertyDescriptor ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Editor
    /// </summary>
    object ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
    {
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Events
    /// </summary>
    EventDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return new EventDescriptorCollection(null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the events
    /// </summary>
    EventDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetEvents()
    {
        return new EventDescriptorCollection(null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the properties
    /// </summary>
    PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        List<TestResultPropertyDescriptor> properties = new List<TestResultPropertyDescriptor>();

        //Add property descriptors for each entry in the dictionary
        foreach (string key in this.Keys)
        {
            properties.Add(new TestResultPropertyDescriptor(key));
        }

        //Get properties also belonging to this class also
        //PropertyDescriptorCollection pdc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this.GetType(), attributes);

        //foreach (PropertyDescriptor oPropertyDescriptor in pdc)
        //{
        //    properties.Add(oPropertyDescriptor);
        //}

        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(properties.ToArray());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// gets the Properties
    /// </summary>
    PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties()
    {
        List<TestResultPropertyDescriptor> properties = new List<TestResultPropertyDescriptor>();

        foreach (string key in this.Keys)
        {
            properties.Add(new TestResultPropertyDescriptor(key));
        }
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(properties.ToArray());

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the property owner
    /// </summary>
    object ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
    {
        return this;
    }

    #endregion Methods

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}`public class TestResultValue
{
    private object _value;
    public object Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
        }

    }
}`
```

This is how I am using it...

```
var items = new ObservableCollection<TestResultRowWrapper>();
        var row = new TestResultRowWrapper();
        row.Add("Random", new TestResultValue() { Value=1.1});
        items.Add(row);

        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = items;
```

Comment: Testresultwrapper is an dictionary which is exactly what you're seeing in your data grid.

Comment: I solved it by implementing IList<T>. So rather than binding to an ObservableCollection, I bind to a custom type that implements IList<T>. Hope this helps someone in the future.